# Do I need spring.jpa.database and spring.jpa.database-platform in application properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, yaml

For Spring Boot application, there are some configuration that seems to be redundant or not mandatory in [Common Application Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html). For this reason, I would like to keep my `application.yml` file simple and remove unnecessary or redundant properties.

So, do I need `spring.jpa.database` and `spring.jpa.database-platform` in application properties?

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:${DB_NAME};DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false
    username: ${DB_USERNAME}
    password: 
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate.format_sql: true
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: 'true'
      path: /h2-console
```

Comment: I could not see any application properties file in that project. I think you mixed the questions.

Comment: can you share your application.yml?